# One To many : 1 Entity has 2 entities related

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to make a relation one to many as follows.

I have a UserProfile Entity, that have some private fields, and it have 2 fields that are another entities:

- MusicalTaste: Id and name
- FavouriteArtist: Id and name.

Initially, I only did a onetoMany relation, because a want that a userProfile has an array of musical tastes and another array of artists.

Well, those are the entities I have right now:

**UserProfile**:

```
myDomain\Entity\UserProfile:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: MyMelomanBundle\Repository\UserProfileRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        aboutMe:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: true
            column: about_me
        image:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: true
        birthDate:
            type: datetime
            column: birth_date
            nullable: true
    oneToMany:
        musicalTaste:
            targetEntity: myDomain\Entity\MusicalTaste
            mappedBy: musicalTaste
            joinColumn:
                name: musicalTaste_id
                referencedColumnName: id
        favouriteArtist:
            targetEntity: myDomain\Entity\FavouriteArtist
            mappedBy: favouriteArtist
            joinColumn:
                name: favouriteArtist_id
                referencedColumnName: id

    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

**MusicalTaste**:

```
myDomain\Entity\MusicalTaste:
    type: entity
    table: musical_taste
    repositoryClass: MyMelomanBundle\Repository\MusicalTasteRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: true
            column: name
    manyToOne:
        userProfile:
            targetEntity: myDomain\Entity\UserProfile
            inversedBy: musicalTaste
            joinColumn:
                name: userProfile_id
                referencedColumName: id
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

**FavouriteArtists**:

```
myDomain\Entity\FavouriteArtist:
    type: entity
    table: favourite_artist
    repositoryClass: MyMelomanBundle\Repository\FavouriteArtistRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: true
            column: name
    manyToOne:
        userProfile:
            targetEntity: myDomain\Entity\UserProfile
            inversedBy: favouriteArtist
            joinColumn:
                name: userProfile_id
                referencedColumName: id
```

When i'm updating the doctrine schema, all looks good, aparently, but if I do:

I have to create a manyToOne relation on MusicalTaste and Favourite Artists? (Prevously I did but no relations were created...) But there is some fails when validating:

$  php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate

```
[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'myDomain\Entity\FavouriteArtist' mapping is invalid:
* The mappings myDomain\Entity\FavouriteArtist#userProfile and myDomain\Entity\UserProfile#favouriteArtist are inconsistent with each other.

[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'myDomain\Entity\MusicalTaste' mapping is invalid:
* The mappings myDomain\Entity\MusicalTaste#userProfile and myDomain\Entity\UserProfile#musicalTaste are inconsistent with each other.

[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'myDomain\Entity\UserProfile' mapping is invalid:
* The association myDomain\Entity\UserProfile#musicalTaste refers to the owning side field myDomain\Entity\MusicalTaste#musicalTaste which does not exist.
* The association myDomain\Entity\UserProfile#favouriteArtist refers to the owning side field myDomain\Entity\FavouriteArtist#favouriteArtist which does not exist
```

How I can fix them? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try "mappedBy: musicalTaste" as "mappedBy: userProfile" in userprofile.yml

Comment: Changing them by userProfile solved them when validating, but why? musicalTaste is a field of userProfile's Entity... Thanks anyway!

Comment: I don't know much details. I thinks it's the doctrine's YML syntax when it wants to use a bridge for bidirectional way. You can read the doctrine website for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mehmet said:

Change "mappedBy: musicalTaste" as "mappedBy: userProfile" in userprofile.yml worked perfectly.